# Could a missing ground connection in a light box disable other fixtures?

Tags: lighting, grounding

I replaced an existing outside light fixture with [these security lights](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MCV0WRA). I properly connected the wires together (including ground). After installing I was reading the install instructions a bit closer and they indicated to connect ground to the Cross Bar, which I did not do :( The light is outside of my sun room and it's connected to the same switch (not sure of the term here, but the same breaker switch turns off both).

A few days later I noticed that my two fan+light fixtures in the sun room are not turning on any longer.

Could the fan+light fixtures no longer working be related to me not screwing ground into the cross bar even though I did connect ground wires? If so, is there any dangers that I should be aware of with me trying to connect ground to the Cross Bar now?

This is my first time posting here, I apologize if I've missed any important info or not followed conventions.

Edit for more info from comments:

- The security lights themselves work fine
- I connected the ground wire from security lights to the ground wire from the existing outlet box

Comment: Do the new security lights work?

Comment: What did you connect ground to?

Comment: Does the new security light work? Is there any indication whether there's power to the other fixtures?

Comment: The security lights themselves work fine.

Comment: I connected the ground wire from security lights to the ground wire from the existing outlet box

Comment: From what we know it's unlikely that the failing fixtures are related. Show a photo of the security light connections if you'd like more help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Isherwood, I made sure to correctly connect the wires and I sealed with silicon caulk so taking a pic of the wires isn’t that easy.

Comment: The ground to the cross bar most likely has nothing to do with the unworking lights. It sounds like the fan and lights in the sunroom feed through one of the boxes that you got into. Probably one of the hot wire or neutral joints that are in those boxes did not get made up properly to continue the feed to the sun room. Check for power at the switches in the sun room and post that information. If the switches have no power then you will need to trace that back to the boxes you were in.

Comment: Thanks @ArchonOSX, I will investigate based on your info.